# How to retrieve videos from playlist from particular category

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

How to retrieve videos from a playlist from a particular category? Is that even possible to do?
I did try this call :

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&maxResults=50&myRating=like&chart=mostPopular&videoCategoryId=10

But no luck

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`Search: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method which returns a collection of search results that match the query parameters specified in the API request.

> By default, a search result set identifies matching [`video`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), [`channel`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels), and [`playlist`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists) resources, but you can also configure queries to only retrieve a specific type of resource.